# Form names with arrays

Tags: php

I would like to convert: `"controllers[page[title_new]]"` to `"controllers[page][title_new]"`. So I can fill a form with input fields like:

```
<?php $name = 'controllers[page[title_new]]' ?>

<input type='text' name='<?= $name; ?>'>
```

After you submit the form you get [$_POST](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) =

```
array(controllers => array(page => array(title_new = '')));
```

Now to display this I would like:

```
<input type='text' name='<?= $name; ?>' value='<?= $_POST[CONVERT($name)]; ?>'>
```

So is there such a `CONVERT` built into PHP? Or how could I do it the best way?

*Please note I left out all validation, escaping, htmlentities, etc. out for readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the following works:

```
$name = 'controllers[page[title_new]]';
$name = str_replace(array('[', ']]'), array('][', ']'), $name);
// Gives: controllers][page][title_new]] -> controllers][page][title_new]

$name = preg_replace('/\]\[/','[', $name, 1);
// Gives: controllers[page][title_new]
```